# proc_open is in whitelist_functions but not available in App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application to App Engine Flexible environment with a custom PHP runtime.
When I try to generate a PDF on the site (using wkhtmltopdf with the laravel-snappy wrapper) I get the error:
 (1/1) LogicException

```
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
in Process.php line 143 
at Process->__construct(array(), null, null, null, 60.0)in Process.php line 195
at Process::fromShellCommandline('/app/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality \'/tmp/knp_snappy5dc8497d489631.19576754.html\' \'/tmp/knp_snappy5dc8497d489f90.93505253.pdf\'', null, null)in AbstractGenerator.php line 520
at AbstractGenerator->executeCommand('/app/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality \'/tmp/knp_snappy5dc8497d489631.19576754.html\' \'/tmp/knp_snappy5dc8497d489f90.93505253.pdf\'')in AbstractGenerator.php line 176
```

The thing is, though, I have proc_open and proc_closed listed in the whitelist_functions line in my app.yaml.

Here is a snippet from my app.yaml:

```
runtime:         custom
env:             flex
api_version:    1

runtime_config:
  document_root:  public
  whitelist_functions: proc_open,proc_close
```

For the sake of trying other approaches, I've also tried including it in a php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name,php_uname,getmypid,proc_open, proc_close"
google_app_engine.disable_functions ="exec,passthru,shell_exec,show_source,symlink,system"
```

Yet I still get the error above.

In case it's relevant, I'll also show my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php

COPY ./ /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/storage/framework/cache \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/framework/cache/data \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/framework/views \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/framework/sessions \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/logs
RUN chmod -R a+rwX /app/storage
RUN chmod a+rwx /app/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT /app/public

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6 libssl-dev libssl1.0 libjpeg62 libpng16-16

EXPOSE 8080
```

... and the relevant bits from my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.9",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "google/cloud": "^0.24.0",
    "superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.3",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x"
},
```

Am I missing something?

**Update:** I'm not sure if this is related, or just another error I'll need to deal with next, but if I attempt to run wkhtmltopdf directly from the command line, I get `error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
But I can't install that because it does not appear to be available for the version of Linux I'm using (Ubuntu 16.04.6).

Comment: Are you using a job queue to execute the HTML to PDF ?

Comment: Yes and no. The larger reports do use queued jobs with the database queue driver. The one I've been using to test my changes does not use a queued job.

Comment: Marian's answer worked, but then I still got the error only when running it with a job queue. The error was resolved by switching all traffic in App Engine to the version I was testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this example: [How to use the image on App Engine Flexible Environment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker/blob/master/php-onbuild/README.md):

> If you need any of those functions, you can add an environment
>   variable WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS.

```
app.yaml:

runtime: php
vm: true
api_version: 1

env_variables:
  WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS: phpinfo,exec
```

Comment: That did it! Turns out that I may have been doing something else wrong, assuming that the ```disable_functions``` in the php.ini was an App Engine thing, when it is not.